# NHibernate discriminator-value="null" not working on base class - filter not applied

Tags: nhibernate

For following class mapping:

```
<class name="Person" table="Person" discriminator-value="null">
    <id name="ID" column="ID" >
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="MasterId" />
    <property name="LongName" column="LONGNAME" />
    <property name="ShortName" column="SHORTNAME" />
    // other stuff here ...
    <subclass name="PersonHistory" discriminator-value="not null">
        <property name="MasterId" />
    </subclass>
</class>
```

when I execute:

```
        var query =
            from lac in session.Query<Person>()
            orderby lac.LongName
            select lac;
        return query.ToList();
```

I get all entries from **Person** table, both with MasterId set to null and not null. Is there a way to get NHibernate fetch only entities with MasterId = null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what I wanted, I've created base class + two subclasses. This is the configuration:

- subclasses with **discriminator-value**:

  ```
  <subclass name="People" discriminator-value="null">
  </subclass>
  <subclass name="PeopleHistory" discriminator-value="not null">
      <property name="MasterRowId" />
  </subclass>
  ```
- discriminator in base **class**:

  ```
  <discriminator column="MasterRowId" />
  ```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [discriminator](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-discriminator) formula in your case?

```
<discriminator formula="case when MasterId is null then 0 else 1 end" />
```

And then have discriminator attribute values set for classes:

- For Person: discriminator-value="0"
- For PersonHistory: discriminator-value="1"